# XNA Sprite Rotation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I'm trying to rotate the "golf_ball" sprite in my code here but I'm having a lot of difficulty. I've checked out tutorials but I've had no luck. My game should basically keep the ball in the air using the paddle for as long as possible. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    // Ball sprite
    Texture2D ballSprite;

    // Ball location
    Vector2 ballPosition = Vector2.Zero;

    // Store some information about the sprite's motion.
    Vector2 ballSpeed = new Vector2(150, 150);

    // Paddle sprite
    Texture2D paddleSprite;

    // Paddle location
    Vector2 paddlePosition;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        // Set the initial paddle location
        paddlePosition = new Vector2(
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2 - paddleSprite.Width / 2,
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - paddleSprite.Height);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        ballSprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("golf_ball");
        paddleSprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Paddle");

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // Move the sprite by speed, scaled by elapsed time
        ballPosition += ballSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        int maxX = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - ballSprite.Width;
        int maxY = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - ballSprite.Height;

        // Check for bounce
        if (ballPosition.X > maxX || ballPosition.X < 0)
            ballSpeed.X *= -1;

        if (ballPosition.Y < 0)
            ballSpeed.Y *= -1;
        else if (ballPosition.Y > maxY)
        {
            // Ball hit the bottom of the screen, so reset ball
            ballPosition.Y = 0;
            ballSpeed.X = 150;
            ballSpeed.Y = 150;
        }


        // Ball and paddle collide?  Check rectangle intersection between objects

        Rectangle ballRect =
            new Rectangle((int)ballPosition.X, (int)ballPosition.Y,
            ballSprite.Width, ballSprite.Height);

        Rectangle handRect =
            new Rectangle((int)paddlePosition.X, (int)paddlePosition.Y,
                paddleSprite.Width, paddleSprite.Height);

        if (ballRect.Intersects(handRect))
        {
            // Increase ball speed
            ballSpeed.Y += 50;
            if (ballSpeed.X < 0)
                ballSpeed.X -= 50;
            else
                ballSpeed.X += 50;

            // Send ball back up the screen
            ballSpeed.Y *= -1;
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
        // Update the paddle's position
        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            paddlePosition.X += 5;
        else if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            paddlePosition.X -= 5;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // Draw the sprite
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(ballSprite, ballPosition, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(paddleSprite, paddlePosition, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433992.aspx Checkout this page, is that what you want? `rotation` argument?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Please try to narrow the code down to the relevant parts.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

As @user3449857 has already pointed out, your code does not actually rotate the sprite.

To begin with, try the following:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(ballSprite, ballPosition, null, Color.White, 1.5f, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);
```

You can see that the 5th argument is for rotation, and that it should have rotated your ball. This takes a float.

Armed with that knowledge, try Googling other tutorials on how to increase rotation.